# Accessing Raspberry Pi GPIOs through Unity project on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi

I'm making a game where I want to control some LEDs when certain events happen. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 running an Android OS from [Emteria](https://emteria.com/). In my research I found a solution that works for Windows not for Android ([found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076986/accessing-raspberry-pi-gpio-ports-through-unity)). Is there any way to control Raspberry Pi GPIOs from a Unity project running on Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.